# Margen inferior en input text de Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

Me gustaría poder quitarle algo de margen inferior a los campos `input`,  ya que mi idea es usar la aplicación en móvil y necesito mucho espacio.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class=" col-md-12  col-xs-12 ">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group row ">
        <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Fecha / Hora Inicio</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm " id="fechaInicio" placeholder="Fecha / Hora Inicio">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Tipo Movimiento</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <option>Tipo Movimiento</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputOrigen" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Origen</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <option>Origen</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputDestino" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Destino</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <option>Destino</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputChofer" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Chofer</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <option>Chofer</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputCamion" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Camión</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
           <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <option>Camión</option>
           </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: La clase `.form-group` añade por defecto un `margin-botom: 1rem`, haz una regla **CSS** que la pise y que se ajuste a lo que necesitas. Recuerda que el inspeccionador de las herramientas de desarrollo de tu navegador es una herramienta indispensable para poder maquetar.

Comment: He creado una clase y se la he aplicado, pensaba que igual había algo especifico de  Bootstrap como un mb-0 o algo asi. Gracias

Comment: Podrías quitar la clase `.form-group` de tus elementos, ya que no necesitas de ella lo único que hacen, que es darle ese `margin-bottom: 1rem` y ponerle en vez la de eso la tuya propia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con bootstrap 4 puedes aplicar las clases `my-0` y `py-0` directamente en tu etiqueta `input` o `.form-group`, con ellos lo que se busca es dejar el margen y padding vertical en 0.

También, si solo quieres alterar el margen inferior puedes reemplazar la **Y** por una **B**, de bottom, `mb-0` y `pb-0`.